# When sending mail with SMTP it breaks utf-8 characters

Tags: python, email, utf-8, outlook, smtp

I wrote a script that sends mail with Python. Generally, this script sends the text it reads from a txt file as an e-mail.
But when the mail goes, the utf-8 characters get corrupted. When I run this script on Linux, I didn't get such an error, but when I run it on Windows I get this error.

Here is my code:

```
try:
    message = open('mailcontent.txt', 'r').read()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error opening mail content file!: {e}")

def send_mail(messages, subject):
    global msg

    try:
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        s = smtplib.SMTP(host="SMTP.office365.com", port=587)
        s.starttls()
        s.login(examplemailfrom, password)

        msg['From'] = examplemailfrom
        msg['To'] = examplemail
        msg['Subject'] = examplesubject

        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain', 'utf-8'))

        s.send_message(msg)

        del msg

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error has occurred!: {e}")
```

Here is "**mailcontent.txt**" file content:

```
Here  İs an example mAİl


Almost all utf-8 characters get corrupted.

how can İ solve thİs?
```

Mail:

[image]

How can i solve this ?

Comment: The default encoding used by `open` varies.  Open explicitly: `message = open('mailcontent.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8').read()`

Comment: @MarkTolonen Seems logical. I'll write after I try if it works or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by opening the Mail content file as follows:

```
message = open('mailcontent.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8').read()
```